# Help visualising immersion of $\mathbb{R}P_3$ in $\mathbb{R^4}$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, projective-space

Theoreticaly, there exist immersions of the real projective space $\mathbb{R}P_3$ in $\mathbb{R^4}$.

If an equation for one is given, eg $f:\mathbb{R}P_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^4}$ you can visualize it as the cross-sections of a hyperplane moving along the orthogonal dimension.

You set the coordinates as $(x,y,z,t)$, where $t$ is time, and imagine  the set of $(x,y,z)$ such that  $(x,y,z,t)$ is in the image of $f$ at the given $t$.

By applying this procedure for the embedding of the real projective plane $\mathbb{R}P_2$ (as was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91981/give-an-explicit-embedding-from-mathbbrp-2-to-mathbbr4)), I've sketched the following example:

[image]

For projective space, I'm having trouble getting either a visualization or an equation (for an immersion). I know if I could "glue" a $3$-ball to the real projective plane then it would give $\mathbb{R}P_3$ . That would mean starting with a point that grows into a sphere instead of loop, but I can't apply the "twisting" without getting cone-like singularities. So that's not a good strategy. I know there's other ways to obtain $\mathbb{R}P_3$, for example gluing two solid tori, but it's hard translating the correct "gluing" to immersion.

Please provide an explicit function for immersion of $\mathbb{R}P_3$ in $\mathbb{R^4}$, or guidance on how to correctly pick the cross-sections in  $\mathbb{R}^3$ along time .

Comment: See if http://www.groupoids.org.uk/outofline/motion.html#motion helps to see what is going on, though it does not give a formula.

Comment: That's interesting, but it's only the projective plane $\mathbb{R}P_2$.  I've got that done. I'm looking for an immersion of  $\mathbb{R}P_3$ in $R^4$. That's probably gonna be more complicated.