# Explicit immersion of $RP^3$ in $R^4$

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

The existence of immersions of real projective 3-space in 4 dimensional Euclidean space was proved by Hirsch (I think) in 1959. I would like to
see an explicit example of such an immersion. Does anyone know of one? Ditto for immersions of four-dimensional real projective space in Euclidean space.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422899/help-visualising-immersion-of-mathbbrp-3-in-mathbbr4